# Error in reading yaml file using `snakeyaml`

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed` when reading yaml file in my code:

Below is my project structure:

```
-rc
 - main
   - java
     - MyMainClass
   - resources
     - application.yaml
```

Here is the sample code:

```
public class LoadYaml {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadYaml.class);

    public void loadYaml() {

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(Config.class));
        InputStream inputStream = this.getClass()
                .getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("resources/application.yaml");
        Config config = yaml.load(inputStream);

        LOGGER.info(config.toString());
    }
```

Below is my custom class for yaml:

```
package org.finra.dapi.parttioncleanup;

import java.util.List;

public class Config {

    private String url;
    private String userName;
    private String pwsKey;
    private List<Tables> tables;

   ....getters and setters
```

Error stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:218)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:176)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:171)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:126)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.java:1177)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:287)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:195)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:107)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:139)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:524)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:452)
    at org.finra.dapi.parttioncleanup.LoadYaml.loadYaml(LoadYaml.java:23)
    at org.finra.dapi.parttioncleanup.LambdaHandler.main(LambdaHandler.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(PushbackInputStream.java:74)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:166)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.init(UnicodeReader.java:92)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:124)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:183)
    ... 15 more
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: This looks like a Maven project structure. If this is part of a Maven build the resources directory will not be on the classpath, the application.yaml file will end up in the root of the classpath.

Comment: @Gimby yes it is maven project, how to fix this?

Comment: ... by listening to what I'm saying?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java class loader bug: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567374/java-class-loader-bug-caused-by-java-io-ioexception-stream-closed)

Comment: @Gimby I removed `/resources` from my path and it worked, thanks